# Two Horizontal Aligned divs with a vertical aligned inner div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to vertically align the second div in my example here.  The text in the one div can vary and can be anywhere from 1-50 characters.  The second div can vary from 4-7 characters but that needs to be vertically aligned if the text in the one div is larger.

html

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="two">result</div>
    <div class="one">This is a long string This is a long string This is a long string This is a long string This is a long string This is a long string This is a long string This is a long string This is a long string</div>
 </div>
```

css

```
div.wrap 
{
    width: 200px;
}

div.one {
    border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
    white-space: normal;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
div.two {
    background-color: #7bbf7b;    
    float: right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mg5wpmur/

Comment: Like [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/chvv40uL/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using display table.

[Have an example!](http://jsfiddle.net/chvv40uL/)

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">        
    <div class="one">This is a long string This is a long string This is a long string This is a long string This is a long string This is a long string This is a long string This is a long string This is a long string</div>
    <div class="two">result</div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
div.wrap 
{
    width: 200px;
    display: table;
}

div.one {
    border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
    white-space: normal;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    display: table-cell;
}
div.two {
    background-color: #7bbf7b;    
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```